# Change kde notifications osd (icon)

Tags: gnome, kde, notification, notify-osd

I changed from Gnome to KDE, really like it so far, but I want to change my notifications icons, like the increase/decrease volume, increase/decrease lighting on keyboard, toggle touchpad. I really liked the ones on gnome, but don't seem to find a solution on how to change them. An example of what I am looking to have https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-can-i-disable-popup-notification-for-volume-control/6968

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**KDE Plasma OSD icons**

Plasma OSD is using icons from the plasma desktop theme - volume OSD icons are in audio.svgz:

[image]

Plasma theme details: https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma5/ThemeDetails

Icons: https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma5/ThemeDetails#.22icons.22_folder

Plasma desktop theme can be changed from the KDE System Settings > Workspace Theme > Desktop Theme

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get some Icon packs. That will change the icons.

Good one to start with could be [Paper](https://store.kde.org/p/1013706/show/page/2).

[image]